# inox browser: build and patch chromium from source

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, browser, patch, privacy

I recently stumbled over a set of patches for chromium which promise to `focus on privacy by disabling data transmission to google`. You can read more about it [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=198763). It originates from a [Archlinux AUR](https://aur4.archlinux.org/packages/inox/) but the pachtes are availabe to [download](https://aur4.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/inox.tar.gz).

I would like to patch Chromium from Source for Ubuntu, but I never did that before. I'm more or less familiar with building from source with `config`, `make` & `make install`, but it seems rather difficult for Chromium. I found some instruction [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Build).

**Can someone provide a proper step-by-step tutorial on how to build and patch chromium from source?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Note that the link to Ubuntu's instructions for building Chromium appears to be heavily outdated.)

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the [Chromium Beta](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-beta) and [Dev](https://launchpad.net/~saiarcot895/+archive/ubuntu/chromium-dev) PPAs.

If you run `apt-get source chromium-browser`, you'll get the source code for the current stable version of Chromium that's in the repos along with the patches that Ubuntu applies on top of Chromium (which are in the `debian/patches` folder). You can add additional patches to be applied to Chromium here, but note that some of the patches you add may conflict or be the same as the patches Ubuntu uses. Also, update the `series` file, which describes what patches to apply and in what order.

The build script is at `debian/rules`. It's quite long, but the most important variable you'll probably be interested in is `GYP_DEFINES`, which is where you would specify the build flags to build Chromium with. For example, if you wanted to build Chromium with `enable_google_now=0`, then add a line saying `GYP_DEFINES += enable_google_now=0` (you can add it around the other lines starting with `GYP_DEFINES`). Note that some build flags on that page conflict with the build flags Ubuntu uses (I know `enable_webrtc` is set to 1 in `debian/rules`).

As for building it, the simplest way would probably be to run `dpkg-buildpackage -b` from the `chromium-browser-*` directory. This will apply the patches, run through the `debian/rules` file, and then make several deb files. If there are build dependencies missing, it should notify you of those and stop the build. You can then install those deb files.

Note that building Chromium takes about 4-5 hours on a 4-core machine and takes about 15 GB of space (with debugging symbols included). Without debugging symbols (if you comment out the line that adds the `-g` flag), I'd estimate that it would take about 7-8 GB of space.

Comment: There is now a github project which does what I was heading for. https://github.com/Eloston/ungoogled-chromium